# Is ''some" equal to "any" in inductive hypothesis?

Tags: proof-writing

For example, in proving the following lemma

***If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $n+1=1+n.$***

Little gave in his book entitled THE NUMBER SYSTEMS OF ANALYSIS the following proof:
Clearly the lemma holds if $n=1.$  Assume as an inductive hypothesis that $n+1=1+n$ for *some* $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Then
\begin{align*}
(n+1)+1&=(1+n)+1\\
&=1+(n+1)
\end{align*}
by associativity. Thus the lemma follows by induction. $\Box$

My question is: Is it true that the italicized "some" equals "any"? That is, the sentence
\begin{gather*}
\text{Assume as an inductive hypothesis that $n+1=1+n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$}
\end{gather*}
says the same thing as the sentence
\begin{gather*}
\text{Assume as an inductive hypothesis that $n+1=1+n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$?}
\end{gather*}
Many thanks.

Comment: No "some $n$" in this context means "a particular $n$."  In this context, "any $n$" would mean the same thing as "every $n$" and once you assume that, there's nothing left to prove!

Comment: We know it is true for $n=1$ since we checked before hand in our base step.  So, we know that there is at least one $n$ for which it works.  Now... we say "suppose it is true for some $n$", in this case initially meaning just the case where $n=1$, but eventually meaning any particular values for which we know it to be true for.  We go on to show that it follows that it must be true for $n+1$ as well.  That is, originally we know it is true for $1$ since we checked that, this and the induction step implies it must also be true for $n=2$, which in turn implies its true for $n=3$ and so on...

Answer (score 1):

No. If you use the second statement, then you implied that the proposition is right, which is the thing that you are proving. This is cycle reasoning.

What i am saying is, the 2nd statement is just the proposition above. You cannot assume that.